# awk: edition and merging of several files

Tags: awk

My awk script

```
awk 'FNR == NR {print; next} !/^HETATM/' file 1 file 2 > file3
```

takes the file 1,

```
ATOM   2333  O   GLY A 302       4.437  -5.416 -15.061  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2334  N   VAL A 303       6.125  -4.263 -14.046  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM   2335  CA  VAL A 303       6.912  -5.471 -13.654  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2336  C   VAL A 303       6.084  -6.281 -12.648  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2337  O   VAL A 303       5.524  -5.658 -11.721  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2338  CB  VAL A 303       8.275  -5.106 -13.041  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2339  CG1 VAL A 303       9.042  -6.345 -12.599  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2340  CG2 VAL A 303       9.110  -4.247 -13.982  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2341  N   THR A 304       6.084  -7.612 -12.777  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM   2342  CA  THR A 304       5.387  -8.568 -11.870  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2343  C   THR A 304       6.401  -9.497 -11.184  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2344  O   THR A 304       6.024 -10.138 -10.181  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2345  CB  THR A 304       4.347  -9.361 -12.666  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2346  CG2 THR A 304       3.359  -8.466 -13.379  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2347  OG1 THR A 304       5.073 -10.157 -13.609  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2348  OXT THR A 304       7.557  -9.744 -11.437  1.00  0.00           O  
TER    2348      THR A 304
HETATM 2349  N   lig C 305       5.333  -3.914  24.369  1.00  0.00           N  
HETATM 2350  N   lig C 305       6.549  -3.483  22.354  1.00  0.00           N  
HETATM 2351  C   lig C 305       8.476   0.870  21.339  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2352  C   lig C 305       8.480  -0.313  22.272  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2353  C   lig C 305       7.515  -1.318  21.616  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2354  C   lig C 305       6.759  -0.499  20.602  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2355  C   lig C 305       5.725  -0.890  19.765  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2356  C   lig C 305       5.391  -0.063  18.682  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2357  C   lig C 305       6.087   1.136  18.438  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2358  C   lig C 305       7.107   1.542  19.296  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2359  C   lig C 305       7.411   0.711  20.359  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2360  C   lig C 305       6.779  -2.149  22.642  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2361  C   lig C 305       4.488  -6.115  24.861  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2362  C   lig C 305       5.020  -6.582  23.664  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2363  C   lig C 305       4.667  -4.783  25.169  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2364  C   lig C 305       5.707  -5.691  22.826  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2365  C   lig C 305       5.847  -4.361  23.208  1.00  0.00           C  
HETATM 2366  O   lig C 305       9.213   1.838  21.395  1.00  0.00           O  
HETATM 2367  O   lig C 305       6.362  -1.559  23.645  1.00  0.00           O  
HETATM 2368 CL   lig C 305       3.637  -7.165  25.918  1.00  0.00          CL  
END
```

removes all the lines starting from HETATM and cut it (at the top of the file1) with the file2:

```
ATOM      1  N   lig   305       5.333  -3.914  24.369  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  N1  lig   305       6.549  -3.483  22.354  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      3  C   lig   305       8.476   0.870  21.339  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      4  C1  lig   305       8.480  -0.313  22.272  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  C2  lig   305       7.515  -1.318  21.616  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  C3  lig   305       6.759  -0.499  20.602  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      7  C4  lig   305       5.725  -0.890  19.765  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      8  C5  lig   305       5.391  -0.063  18.682  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      9  C6  lig   305       6.087   1.136  18.438  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     10  C7  lig   305       7.107   1.542  19.296  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     11  C8  lig   305       7.411   0.711  20.359  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     12  C9  lig   305       6.779  -2.149  22.642  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     13  C10 lig   305       4.488  -6.115  24.861  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     14  C11 lig   305       5.020  -6.582  23.664  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     15  C12 lig   305       4.667  -4.783  25.169  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     16  C13 lig   305       5.707  -5.691  22.826  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     17  C14 lig   305       5.847  -4.361  23.208  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     18  O   lig   305       9.213   1.838  21.395  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     19  O1  lig   305       6.362  -1.559  23.645  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     20 Cl   lig   305       3.637  -7.165  25.918  1.00  0.00          Cl
ATOM     21  H   lig   305       6.895  -3.840  21.504  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     22  H1  lig   305       8.131  -0.031  23.243  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     23  H2  lig   305       9.460  -0.719  22.413  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     24  H3  lig   305       7.967  -2.125  21.077  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     25  H4  lig   305       5.213  -1.770  19.935  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     26  H5  lig   305       4.621  -0.339  18.053  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     27  H6  lig   305       5.841   1.716  17.621  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     28  H7  lig   305       7.615   2.427  19.144  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     29  H8  lig   305       4.911  -7.572  23.395  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     30  H9  lig   305       4.273  -4.429  26.055  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     31  H10 lig   305       6.106  -6.020  21.933  1.00  0.00           H
```

so the results (combined file) looks like:

```
ATOM      1  N   lig   305       5.333  -3.914  24.369  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  N1  lig   305       6.549  -3.483  22.354  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      3  C   lig   305       8.476   0.870  21.339  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      4  C1  lig   305       8.480  -0.313  22.272  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  C2  lig   305       7.515  -1.318  21.616  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  C3  lig   305       6.759  -0.499  20.602  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      7  C4  lig   305       5.725  -0.890  19.765  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      8  C5  lig   305       5.391  -0.063  18.682  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      9  C6  lig   305       6.087   1.136  18.438  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     10  C7  lig   305       7.107   1.542  19.296  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     11  C8  lig   305       7.411   0.711  20.359  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     12  C9  lig   305       6.779  -2.149  22.642  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     13  C10 lig   305       4.488  -6.115  24.861  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     14  C11 lig   305       5.020  -6.582  23.664  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     15  C12 lig   305       4.667  -4.783  25.169  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     16  C13 lig   305       5.707  -5.691  22.826  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     17  C14 lig   305       5.847  -4.361  23.208  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     18  O   lig   305       9.213   1.838  21.395  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     19  O1  lig   305       6.362  -1.559  23.645  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     20 Cl   lig   305       3.637  -7.165  25.918  1.00  0.00          Cl
ATOM     21  H   lig   305       6.895  -3.840  21.504  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     22  H1  lig   305       8.131  -0.031  23.243  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     23  H2  lig   305       9.460  -0.719  22.413  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     24  H3  lig   305       7.967  -2.125  21.077  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     25  H4  lig   305       5.213  -1.770  19.935  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     26  H5  lig   305       4.621  -0.339  18.053  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     27  H6  lig   305       5.841   1.716  17.621  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     28  H7  lig   305       7.615   2.427  19.144  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     29  H8  lig   305       4.911  -7.572  23.395  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     30  H9  lig   305       4.273  -4.429  26.055  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     31  H10 lig   305       6.106  -6.020  21.933  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM   2333  O   GLY A 302       4.437  -5.416 -15.061  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2334  N   VAL A 303       6.125  -4.263 -14.046  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM   2335  CA  VAL A 303       6.912  -5.471 -13.654  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2336  C   VAL A 303       6.084  -6.281 -12.648  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2337  O   VAL A 303       5.524  -5.658 -11.721  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2338  CB  VAL A 303       8.275  -5.106 -13.041  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2339  CG1 VAL A 303       9.042  -6.345 -12.599  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2340  CG2 VAL A 303       9.110  -4.247 -13.982  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2341  N   THR A 304       6.084  -7.612 -12.777  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM   2342  CA  THR A 304       5.387  -8.568 -11.870  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2343  C   THR A 304       6.401  -9.497 -11.184  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2344  O   THR A 304       6.024 -10.138 -10.181  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2345  CB  THR A 304       4.347  -9.361 -12.666  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2346  CG2 THR A 304       3.359  -8.466 -13.379  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2347  OG1 THR A 304       5.073 -10.157 -13.609  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2348  OXT THR A 304       7.557  -9.744 -11.437  1.00  0.00           O  
TER    2348      THR A 304
END
```

how I could modify it to paste all strings of file 2 at the bottom of the edited file 1, just before the string started with 'END' ? (in the file 1 there is always last line consisted of the END record). Here is the expected output:

```
ATOM   2333  O   GLY A 302       4.437  -5.416 -15.061  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2334  N   VAL A 303       6.125  -4.263 -14.046  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM   2335  CA  VAL A 303       6.912  -5.471 -13.654  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2336  C   VAL A 303       6.084  -6.281 -12.648  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2337  O   VAL A 303       5.524  -5.658 -11.721  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2338  CB  VAL A 303       8.275  -5.106 -13.041  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2339  CG1 VAL A 303       9.042  -6.345 -12.599  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2340  CG2 VAL A 303       9.110  -4.247 -13.982  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2341  N   THR A 304       6.084  -7.612 -12.777  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM   2342  CA  THR A 304       5.387  -8.568 -11.870  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2343  C   THR A 304       6.401  -9.497 -11.184  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2344  O   THR A 304       6.024 -10.138 -10.181  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2345  CB  THR A 304       4.347  -9.361 -12.666  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2346  CG2 THR A 304       3.359  -8.466 -13.379  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM   2347  OG1 THR A 304       5.073 -10.157 -13.609  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM   2348  OXT THR A 304       7.557  -9.744 -11.437  1.00  0.00           O  
TER    2348      THR A 304
ATOM      1  N   lig   305       5.333  -3.914  24.369  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  N1  lig   305       6.549  -3.483  22.354  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      3  C   lig   305       8.476   0.870  21.339  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      4  C1  lig   305       8.480  -0.313  22.272  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      5  C2  lig   305       7.515  -1.318  21.616  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      6  C3  lig   305       6.759  -0.499  20.602  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      7  C4  lig   305       5.725  -0.890  19.765  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      8  C5  lig   305       5.391  -0.063  18.682  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM      9  C6  lig   305       6.087   1.136  18.438  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     10  C7  lig   305       7.107   1.542  19.296  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     11  C8  lig   305       7.411   0.711  20.359  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     12  C9  lig   305       6.779  -2.149  22.642  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     13  C10 lig   305       4.488  -6.115  24.861  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     14  C11 lig   305       5.020  -6.582  23.664  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     15  C12 lig   305       4.667  -4.783  25.169  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     16  C13 lig   305       5.707  -5.691  22.826  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     17  C14 lig   305       5.847  -4.361  23.208  1.00  0.00           C
ATOM     18  O   lig   305       9.213   1.838  21.395  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     19  O1  lig   305       6.362  -1.559  23.645  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM     20 Cl   lig   305       3.637  -7.165  25.918  1.00  0.00          Cl
ATOM     21  H   lig   305       6.895  -3.840  21.504  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     22  H1  lig   305       8.131  -0.031  23.243  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     23  H2  lig   305       9.460  -0.719  22.413  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     24  H3  lig   305       7.967  -2.125  21.077  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     25  H4  lig   305       5.213  -1.770  19.935  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     26  H5  lig   305       4.621  -0.339  18.053  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     27  H6  lig   305       5.841   1.716  17.621  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     28  H7  lig   305       7.615   2.427  19.144  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     29  H8  lig   305       4.911  -7.572  23.395  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     30  H9  lig   305       4.273  -4.429  26.055  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM     31  H10 lig   305       6.106  -6.020  21.933  1.00  0.00           H
END
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: added to the topic!

Comment: Any time you post sample input/output that requires scroll bars to read you lose a the interest of a significant number of people who might be able to help you. Please post a [mcve] emphasis on **minimal**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- ignore all lines starting with `HETATM` (would also include strings like `HETATM123` and `HETATM_xyz`)
- remove all lines that start with `END` (would also include strings like `ENDGAME` and `END_of_the_world`)
- both assumptions apply to all input files
- if either assumption is invalid OP should update the question with more details about which lines to discard as well as a more representative (and preferably smaller/minimum) set of input data

Using a smaller set of sample input:

```
==> file1 <==
ATOM   2347  OG1 THR A 304       5.073 -10.157 -13.609  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM   2348  OXT THR A 304       7.557  -9.744 -11.437  1.00  0.00           O
TER    2348      THR A 304
HETATM 2349  N   lig C 305       5.333  -3.914  24.369  1.00  0.00           N
HETATM 2367  O   lig C 305       6.362  -1.559  23.645  1.00  0.00           O
END

==> file2 <==
ATOM      1  N   lig   305       5.333  -3.914  24.369  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  N1  lig   305       6.549  -3.483  22.354  1.00  0.00           N
```

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk '!/^HETATM|^END/; END {print "END"}' file1 file2
ATOM   2347  OG1 THR A 304       5.073 -10.157 -13.609  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM   2348  OXT THR A 304       7.557  -9.744 -11.437  1.00  0.00           O
TER    2348      THR A 304
ATOM      1  N   lig   305       5.333  -3.914  24.369  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  N1  lig   305       6.549  -3.483  22.354  1.00  0.00           N
END
```